# How do you find what is in a JComboBox in a different scope?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have this:

```
{
...
{
    String[] forRussell3 = load2ery.load2er();

    JComboBox monsterComboBox = new JComboBox(forRussell3);
    frame.add(monsterComboBox);
    monsterComboBox.setBounds(900, 160, 200, 30);
}

...

{

    MouseListener a2 = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        String whatMonster = monsterComboBox.getSelectedItem();

    }
};
    monsterComboBox.addMouseListener(a2);
}
```

But my IDE tels me: "`monsterComboBox` can not resolved" in `a2`

I can't place `monsterComboBox` outside of the method because `forRussell3` is created within the method.

How can I find what is in `monsterComboBox`?

Comment: no one knows how to fix this?

Comment: that was a stupid mistake, I just added a final modifier to monsterComboBox to fix it.

Comment: use ItemListener (I know that everywhere is ActionListener), notice ItemListener always fired twice SELECTED and DESELECTED, follows tutorial about ItemListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

monsterComboBox is out of scope, it is enclosed with {}. Declare JComboBox monsterBox; outside of these braces, and initialise the variable inside them.